# Pandas find duplicate concatenated values across selected columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, set

I want to find duplicates in a selection of columns of a `df`,

```
# converts the sub df into matrix
mat = df[['idx', 'a', 'b']].values
str_dict = defaultdict(set)

for x in np.ndindex(mat.shape[0]):
    concat = ''.join(str(x) for x in mat[x][1:])
    # take idx as values of each key a + b
    str_dict[concat].update([mat[x][0]])

dups = {}
for key in str_dict.keys():
    dup = str_dict[key]
    if len(dup) < 2:
        continue

    dups[key] = dup
```

The code finds duplicates of the concatenation of `a` and `b`.  Uses the concatenation as key for a set `defaultdict` (`str_dict`), updates the key with `idx` values; finally uses a `dict` (`dups`) to store any concatenation if the length of its value (set) is >= 2.

I am wondering if there is a better way to do that in terms of efficiency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just concatenate and convert to set:

```
res = set(df['a'].astype(str) + df['b'].astype(str))
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'idx': [1, 2, 3],
                   'a': [4, 4, 5],
                   'b': [5, 5,6]})

res = set(df['a'].astype(str) + df['b'].astype(str))

print(res)

# {'56', '45'}
```

---

If you need to map indices too:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'idx': [1, 2, 3],
                   'a': [41, 4, 5],
                   'b': [3, 13, 6]})

df['conc'] = (df['a'].astype(str) + df['b'].astype(str))
df = df.reset_index()
res = df.groupby('conc')['index'].apply(set).to_dict()

print(res)
# {'413': {0, 1}, '56': {2}}
```

Comment: how to get the `idx` values associated with each `a` + `b` concatenation as well, as stated in my op

Comment: @daiyue, How do you deal with duplicates? Do you want a list of row index if values are duplicated?

Comment: the return should be a `dict` that takes each duplicated concatenation as key and the `idx` column value as the key's value.

Comment: @daiyue, My question is: What if one key has more than one column value?

Comment: oh, in my code, `str_dict` is a `defaultdict(set)`, so the value of each key is a set

Comment: what if I only want to keep the set whose size is > 1

Comment: With your result, `res2 = {k: v for k, v in res.items() if len(v) > 1}`

Comment: wondering if it can be put in the `apply` using `lambda` function

Comment: @daiyue - probably, feel free to ask as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the column you need before `drop_duplicate`

```
df[['a','b']].drop_duplicates().astype(str).apply(np.sum,1).tolist()
Out[1027]: ['45', '56']
```

Comment: Hmm, say you have column `a = [41, 4, 5], b = [3, 13, 5]`, this wouldn't work, right? As you would get `'413'` twice ?

Comment: @jpp just forgot adding axis=1 for apply :-)

Comment: With my example data I get `['413', '413', '56']`; I think we need to convert to set at the end.

Comment: @jpp I should get the same